# Past information between activities using Json api

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to make an app that shows id and title and whenever some user is clicked, it should go to next activity and show id, userId, title, body, all this coming from implementing REST API from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post.

I know I have to past it with the intent, but do not know quite how to use it

this is the MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val retrofit= Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
        .addConverterFactory(create())
        .build()

    val api = retrofit.create(ApiService:: class.java)

    api.fetchAllPosts().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Post>> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Post>>, response: Response<List<Post>>) {
            showData(response.body()!!)
            Log.d("jv", "onResponse")
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Post>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("jv", "onFailure")
        }
    })

}

private fun showData(posts: List<Post>) {
    recyclerView.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        adapter = PostsAdapter(posts)
    }

}
```

}

this is the adapter

```
class PostsAdapter(private val posts: List<Post>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.post_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = posts.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.userId.text= "Userid:" + posts[position].userId.toString()
        holder.id1.text= "id:" + posts[position].id.toString()
        holder.title.text= "Title:" + posts[position].title
        holder.body.text= "Body:" + posts[position].body
    }
    class ViewHolder (itemView:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val userId: TextView = itemView.userid
        val id1: TextView = itemView.id1
        val title: TextView = itemView.title
        val body: TextView = itemView.body
    }
}
```

this is the post_row layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_check_circle_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/userid"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/photo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/photo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id1"
        tools:text="1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/body"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/photo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userid"
        tools:text="JV" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/photo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        tools:text="JV" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `Post` object to the next activity as a `Serializable` as following.

• At the first step, the `Post` class should implement `Serializable` interface:

```
class Post : Serializable {
     // ...
}
```

• Second step: When the user clicks on each item, put the related `Post` object to the `Intent` extras:

```
val intent = Intent(applicationContext, NextActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("post", post)
startActivity(intent)
```

• Third step: In `onCreate` of `NextActivity`, get the object from `Intent` extras:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val post = intent.getSerializableExtra("post") as Post
    // ...
}
```

---

## * EDIT

I have changed your code to listen to the `RecyclerView` item clicks. In this way, some changes happened to `MainActivity` and `PostsAdapter` classes as well as adding `OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener`. Notice that `Post` class should implement `Serializable`.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
            .addConverterFactory(create())
            .build()

        val api = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)

        api.fetchAllPosts().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Post>> {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Post>>, response: Response<List<Post>>) {
                showData(response.body()!!)
                Log.d("jv", "onResponse")
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Post>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("jv", "onFailure")
            }
        })

    }

    override fun onItemClick(post: Post) {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, NextActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("post", post)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun showData(posts: List<Post>) {
        recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            adapter = PostsAdapter(posts, this@MainActivity)
        }
    }

}
```

**PostsAdapter.kt**

```
class PostsAdapter(
    private val posts: List<Post>,
    private val itemClickListener: OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.post_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = posts.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.userId.text = "Userid:" + posts[position].userId.toString()
        holder.id1.text = "id:" + posts[position].id.toString()
        holder.title.text = "Title:" + posts[position].title
        holder.body.text = "Body:" + posts[position].body
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                itemClickListener.onItemClick(posts[adapterPosition])
            }
        }

        val userId: TextView = itemView.userid
        val id1: TextView = itemView.id1
        val title: TextView = itemView.title
        val body: TextView = itemView.body
    }

}
```

**OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener.kt**

```
interface OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {

    fun onItemClick(post: Post)
}
```

**Post.kt**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import java.io.Serializable

data class Post(
    @SerializedName("userId") val userId: Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("title") val title: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("body") val body: String? = null
) : Serializable
```

**NextActivity.kt**

```
class NextActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_next)

        val post = intent.getSerializableExtra("post") as Post

        // do whatever you want with post!
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. could you please be more specific on where the code goes. I can not figure it out

Comment: You're welcome :) Please share more code of `Post` class and the next activity.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! above I posted the hole code for the postadapter class, and for the next activity I have not implement it yet, I was trying to figure out how to pass the values first

Comment: Do you implement some code listening to the RecyclerView item click?

Comment: Not yet, no. So far I have just listed them

Comment: I have edited the answer. I assumed that your code works correctly to fetch and show the list of posts, then I have added extra codes.

Comment: in Post.tk I get and error on ":Serializable", it says it cannot acces it

Comment: Did you copy exactly `Post.kt` that I shared?

Comment: That was it, thanks! could you help me out doing the code for the next activity?

Comment: Till here, we pass the selected post to the next activity. What do you want to do in it?

Comment: one post has id, userid, title and body, so what I want to do is in the first screen is show userdit and title, then when clicked, the next activity would show all the information but just for the post clicked

Comment: Thanks for mark as answer :) Ok, now you have all of the post information in the NextActivity and you can show them. So what's the problem?

Comment: You can put some `TextView`s in the next activity layout, then after `val post = intent.getSerializableExtra("post") as Post` in onCreate (as I wrote in the answer), assign values from `post` to the `TextView`s. For example: `titleTextView.text = post.title`

Comment: no, thanks to you! maybe you could check this out too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452258/change-color-of-twenty-first-post-from-api/58455483#58455483

Comment: Ok. I'll check it out.

Comment: could help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59241746/how-to-implement-search-bar-post-title-coming-from-api

Answer (score 0):

To pass an object from one activity to another, your class `Post` should implement either `Serializable` or `Parcelable` interfaces.

```
data class Post(val title: String, ... ): Serializable
```

Then you can put object inside the intent. In your `RecyclerAdapter`

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    ...
    holder.body.text= "Body:" + posts[position].body
    holder.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(holder.context, ActivityYouArePassingTo::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Post", posts[position])
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

In the activity that you are navigating to (here `ActivityYouArePassingTo`)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        ...
        // Here is the post from previous activity
        val post = intent.getSerializableExtra("Post") as Post
}
```

Comment: could you please be more specific on where the code goes. I can not figure it out